# Prove that for all constants $a, b>1$, $\log_a{n}$ is $\Theta(\log_b{n})$

Tags: asymptotics

So far I have established that I should be showing the following relationship:

$k_{1}$ $\leq\ \frac{\log_a{n}}{\log_b{n}} \leq\ k_{2}$ where $k_{1}, k_{2}$ $>$ 0

but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the change of base formula, we have

$$\frac{\log_a(n)}{\log_b(n)}=\log_a(b)$$

And then notice that

$$0<\log_a(b)<b$$

Comment: Is it not:

$$\frac{\log_a(n)}{\log_b(n)}=\log_b(a)$$

Comment: @user402081 No, that is not.  Take $a=2,b=4$, for example.

Comment: @user402081 No, I can assure you its right XD

Comment: Sorry, I just started using Stack Exchange so I'm not getting the hang of refreshing comments just yet. I don't get how you got to that point?

Comment: Is it just a rule that log base x y = (log base y x) ^-1?

Comment: @user402081 See [this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/brz1atxkzs)

Comment: @user402081 I used $\log_b(n)=\frac{\log_a(n)}{\log_a(b)}$, which is the change of base formula.

Comment: How did you find the upper bound?

Comment: @user402081 Logarithms obvious decrease the number inside it, right?

Comment: Yeah but you would never even get remotely close to b no matter what numbers you put inside

Comment: @user402081 And thus, it is an upper bound.  QED?